# HTML Div with data and status at top right corner

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this working but could not find anything on the web. What I need  is a simple div (110px Height * 230px Width). It has two texts on it (A Title and a description). But I need a to show a status on the top right corner across with some text.

Below is the mockup picture of what I am trying o achieve.

[image]

Can somebody help me on this..

- Girija

Comment: do you have any code? Also, you will probably need an image of the status ribbon.

Comment: I want it to be a div with text, that can be updated. Not an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/8474/) i snipped it from this : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/corner-ribbon/

you can adjust how ever you want`.`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

1. float or
2. absolute/fixed position
3. overflow:hidden

   and transform:rotate(45deg);

Answer (score 0):

Under those circumstances I usually relatively position the containing div and then

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

the relevant tag you chose to use, Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I give each answer 2 minutes of my time. Here is my effort to solve this
html

```
<div class="wrapper status1">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Css

```
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
}
.wrapper h2 {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper p {
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 line-height: 18px;
}
.wrapper .status1 {
  background-image: url(image1.png);
}
.wrapper .status2 {
  background-image: url(image2.png);
}
.wrapper .status3 {
  background-image: url(image3.png);
}
```

Comment: Use thet "status1" class to switch between the images you will use. CSS has limited capability with slanted text. Images are your best bet. This is a good start. You still have a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it... http://jsfiddle.net/PrghL/

**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
      <div class="status">Status</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .wrapper{
        width:230px;
    height:110px;
    background:#00AB66;   
        position:relative;

    }
.status{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:0;
    transform:rotate(47deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(47deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(47deg); /* Safari and Chrome */


}
```

But if I were you I would use an image for the status. It would look more professional, and neater.

If you used an image you would just remove the transform on the status div. And then play around with the location of the image to put it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

http://jsfiddle.net/2Tdvf/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div>Header</div>
<div>Description</div>
<div>STATUS</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
font-family: arial;
font-size:13px;
width: 230px;
height: 110px;
background:green;
color:#fff;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
padding:7px;
```

}

```
.container>div:last-child{
position:absolute;
top:8%;
right:-6%;
transform:rotate(45deg);
width:70px;
background:#333;
text-align:center;
```

}

```
.container>div:nth-child(1){
font-size:1.2em;
margin-bottom:5px;
```

}